# SQL Transactional Replication - Removing Articles

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

I have a transactional replication setup between database 'A' and 'B'. If I remove articles from the publication, and save the changes, will this immediately get reflected to all current subscribers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is

- Sync data between publish server and transaction server
- Now drop the publication and subscription
- you can again setup publication and subscription with @sync_type = 'replication support only'
- This would not require again snapshot to be created since data is same in both publisher and subscriber
- In SQL 2005 we have an option to create the tables on both transaction and publish server, populate dataset and setup replication on top of it
- Reference article http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1117